# Почему не отправляется письмо на gmail с локального сервера (используя sendmail)

Tags: php, sendmail, openserver

На будущем сайте будет реализована система отправки сообщений на почту пользователей. Пока тестирую на OpenServer.
На почту mail.ru отправляется без проблем. На яндекс-почту тоже.
Проблема в том, что на gmail вообще ничего не приходит, хотя, судя по логам sendmail, все прекрасно отправляется. Сообщения отправляю со своего ящика mail.ru с шифрованием SSL

Comment: В спаме смотрели?

Comment: Попробуйте отправить от какого либо другого адреса - google очень часто кидает в спам, а порой и вообще удаляет письма с ненадежных адресов. И обычно считает что все что идет с mail.ru  -  ненадежно.

Comment: Блин, точно ведь. Спасибо :)

Comment: @DantheHat помойка mail.ru получила международный статус))

Comment: Google требует spf и dkim, а лучше - dmarc.

Answer (score 1):

Gmail требует reverse-dns запись, это когда IP указывает на домен. Без этой настройки письма не то что в спам добавятся - вместо отправки будет просто ошибка. А настройку эту может проставить только владелец подсети (ваш провайдер). То есть если вам нужна стабильная отправка письма: пользуйтесь внешним почтовым сервером и SMTP соединением к нему из PHP.

Или отправка писем без лишнего PHP-кода, и создания всяческих подписей, со своего ящика gmail. Под root в Linux: установить postfix (на тот-же сервер, где PHP), настроить в нём проксирование отправки писем через [smtp.gmail.com]:587, указать в php.ini `sendmail_path` , `sendmail_from`: и после этого PHP функция `mail` заработает корректно, через smtp-сервер gmail, и будет отправлять письма от имени вашей гугловской почты. Пошаговые инструкции вы найдёте по запросам ubuntu-postfix-gmail-smtp и php-use-postfix.

Кстати почтовый сервер можно недорого арендовать, [например на amazon](https://aws.amazon.com/ru/ses/faqs/) - там все настройки можно сделать из web-интерфейса без углубления в тему: у бесплатной гугл-почты очень маленький дневной лимит - 500/день, а в амазоне можно попросить и на 200К/день.

При ручной настройке почтового сервера прямо у хостера не забудьте указать в dns корректные для вашего домена spf, dkim подписи и reverse-dns(обратиться в поддержку к хостинг-провайдеру). Но так мудрить я бы советовал только из любопытства, или работодатель очень просит "всё своё": будут проблемы с доверием к вашему почтовому серверу, которые решаться будут сложнее чем во всех вариантах выше.

Answer (score 0):

Файл класса

```
<?php
```

/**
* SendMailSmtpClass
* 
* Класс для отправки писем через SMTP с авторизацией
* Может работать через SSL протокол
* Тестировалось на почтовых серверах yandex.ru, mail.ru и gmail.com
* 
* @author Ipatov Evgeniy 
* @version 1.0
*/
class SendMailSmtpClass {

```
/**
* 
* @var string $smtp_username - логин
* @var string $smtp_password - пароль
* @var string $smtp_host - хост
* @var string $smtp_from - от кого
* @var integer $smtp_port - порт
* @var string $smtp_charset - кодировка
*
*/   
public $smtp_username;
public $smtp_password;
public $smtp_host;
public $smtp_from;
public $smtp_port;
public $smtp_charset;

public function __construct($smtp_username, $smtp_password, $smtp_host, $smtp_from, $smtp_port = 25, $smtp_charset = "utf-8") {
    $this->smtp_username = $smtp_username;
    $this->smtp_password = $smtp_password;
    $this->smtp_host = $smtp_host;
    $this->smtp_from = $smtp_from;
    $this->smtp_port = $smtp_port;
    $this->smtp_charset = $smtp_charset;
}

/**
* Отправка письма
* 
* @param string $mailTo - получатель письма
* @param string $subject - тема письма
* @param string $message - тело письма
* @param string $headers - заголовки письма
*
* @return bool|string В случаи отправки вернет true, иначе текст ошибки    *
*/
function send($mailTo, $subject, $message, $headers) {
    $contentMail = "Date: " . date("D, d M Y H:i:s") . " UT\r\n";
    $contentMail .= 'Subject: =?' . $this->smtp_charset . '?B?'  . base64_encode($subject) . "=?=\r\n";
    $contentMail .= $headers . "\r\n";
    $contentMail .= $message . "\r\n";

    try {
        if(!$socket = @fsockopen($this->smtp_host, $this->smtp_port, $errorNumber, $errorDescription, 30)){
            throw new Exception($errorNumber.".".$errorDescription);
        }
        if (!$this->_parseServer($socket, "220")){
            throw new Exception('Connection error');
        }

        $server_name = $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"];
        fputs($socket, "HELO $server_name\r\n");
        if (!$this->_parseServer($socket, "250")) {
            fclose($socket);
            throw new Exception('Error of command sending: HELO');
        }

        fputs($socket, "AUTH LOGIN\r\n");
        if (!$this->_parseServer($socket, "334")) {
            fclose($socket);
            throw new Exception('Autorization error');
        }



        fputs($socket, base64_encode($this->smtp_username) . "\r\n");
        if (!$this->_parseServer($socket, "334")) {
            fclose($socket);
            throw new Exception('Autorization error');
        }

        fputs($socket, base64_encode($this->smtp_password) . "\r\n");
        if (!$this->_parseServer($socket, "235")) {
            fclose($socket);
            throw new Exception('Autorization error');
        }

        fputs($socket, "MAIL FROM: <".$this->smtp_username.">\r\n");
        if (!$this->_parseServer($socket, "250")) {
            fclose($socket);
            throw new Exception('Error of command sending: MAIL FROM');
        }

        $mailTo = ltrim($mailTo, '<');
        $mailTo = rtrim($mailTo, '>');
        fputs($socket, "RCPT TO: <" . $mailTo . ">\r\n");     
        if (!$this->_parseServer($socket, "250")) {
            fclose($socket);
            throw new Exception('Error of command sending: RCPT TO');
        }

        fputs($socket, "DATA\r\n");     
        if (!$this->_parseServer($socket, "354")) {
            fclose($socket);
            throw new Exception('Error of command sending: DATA');
        }

        fputs($socket, $contentMail."\r\n.\r\n");
        if (!$this->_parseServer($socket, "250")) {
            fclose($socket);
            throw new Exception("E-mail didn't sent");
        }

        fputs($socket, "QUIT\r\n");
        fclose($socket);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        return  $e->getMessage();
    }
    return true;
}

private function _parseServer($socket, $response) {
    while (@substr($responseServer, 3, 1) != ' ') {
        if (!($responseServer = fgets($socket, 256))) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    if (!(substr($responseServer, 0, 3) == $response)) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;

}
}
```

В файле обработки

```
require_once "SendMailSmtpClass.php";
    $mailSMTP = new SendMailSmtpClass('yourmail@gmail.com', 'password', 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com', 'From', 465);
    $headers= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8\r\n";
    $headers .= "From: From<yourmail@gmail.com>\r\n";
    $result =  $mailSMTP->send('yourmail@gmail.com', 'Subject', "Text", $headers);
```